# Resolving branch name in raw.githubusercontent.com link

Tags: github, github-api

Having a link, like that
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG/REPO/master/path/to/file (**master** is a branch name)

How can I get a link with **hash** instead

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG/REPO/278e0bd7df799a5d5fef873333ccac776e0d0e87/path/to/file

I want to avoid using `git` utilities, or making complex queries to GitHub API.

Comment: You need to resolve the branch name to a hash,  Your choices are to do that with the `git` command, or the GitHub API.  Those are the only options.